# Js challenge and redirect for ddos attacks

Tags: nginx, redirect, proxy, cloudflare, ddos

I want to create a js challenge like the Cloudfler js challenge to prevent Ddos attacks.  when a visitor open the address, he is first transferred to a server with a different IP, and if he confirms the js challenge, he returns to the address again and the contents of the site are executed for him.  Can anyone help using with Nginx or anything else?  I dont want use cloudflare.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is 3rd party nginx module to prevent DDoS attacks with JS testing: https://github.com/C0nw0nk/Nginx-Lua-Anti-DDoS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user973254 mentioned you can use [Nginx-Lua-Anti-DDoS](https://github.com/C0nw0nk/Nginx-Lua-Anti-DDoS#nginx-lua-anti-ddos). There is also [ngx_http_js_challenge_module](https://github.com/simon987/ngx_http_js_challenge_module) which faces some limitations.